# How to disable Heroku email notifications for an app?

Tags: notifications, heroku

How to disable [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) email notifications for an app, while still remaining a collaborator? I didn't find a way to configure this in Heroku dashboard web UI.

Messages like these, for example:

> The percentage of failed requests for [app-name] has
>   exceeded your threshold setting of 5.0%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- not per app, per user. If these are getting noisy, you'll want to turn off email notifications entirely for that feature, or filter them out with something like Gmail filters.

Comment: Ok, not quite optimal, but thanks for the authoritative answer!

Comment: @Jonik Where the notifications can be disabled per user?